# How to generate multiple PDF from array of objects in Node.js and PDFKit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate PDF files from an array of objects. I am initially able to generate the PDFs using the objects first and last name. The issue I am having is that the following error is occurring every time I run the file `Error [ERR_STREAM_PUSH_AFTER_EOF]: stream.push() after EOF`. I believe it is something to do with `p.end()`. I haven't been able to figure it out. Here is what I have at the moment.

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit')
const fs = require('fs')

const students = [
  { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
  { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' }
]

const pdfArr = []

students.forEach(s => {
  pdfArr.push(new PDFDocument())
  pdfArr.forEach(p => {
    p.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${s.firstName}${s.lastName}.pdf`))
    p.fontSize(25).text(`Hello ${s.firstName}`, 100, 100)
    p.end()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is being caused by the nested `.forEach` loops. When accessing the second student it then starts by looping through the previous student's PDF and tries to set it to a new file stream that has already called `.end()`.

Try doing something like this:

```
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit')
const fs = require('fs')

const students = [
  { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
  { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe' }
]

const pdfArr = []

students.forEach(s => {
  let p = new PDFDocument();
  p.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${s.firstName}${s.lastName}.pdf`))
  p.fontSize(25).text(`Hello ${s.firstName}`, 100, 100)
  p.end();

  pdfArr.push(p);

});
```

Hope this helps!